# Using LESS/CSS to apply a custom font to all characters EXCEPT the ampersand

Tags: css, less, font-face, unicode-range

I have the following:

```
@font-mensch: 'menschmensch_bold', "wf_SegoeUI","Segoe UI","Segoe","Segoe WP", Frutiger, "Frutiger Linotype", "Dejavu Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
@font-face {
    font-family: 'menschmensch_bold';
    src: url('font/mensch-bold-wf-webfont.eot');
    src: url('font/mensch-bold-wf-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
      url('font/mensch-bold-wf-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
      url('font/mensch-bold-wf-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
      url('font/mensch-bold-wf-webfont.svg#menschmensch_bold') format('svg');
     font-weight: normal;
     font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    /* Ampersand fallback font */
    font-family: 'sans-serif';
    unicode-range: ~"U+270C";
}
```

The custom font is getting applied, but because the ampersand is not supported with Mensch, I'm trying to conditionally apply sans-serif to the font if it's an ampersand.  The above code isn't working - the ampersands just don't show up.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `unicode-range: ~"U+270C";` supposed to do? Is that valid syntax? I would suspect that property value is being ignored. Also, what is `@font-mensch`? I'm not acquainted with that syntax. Can you also show us the CSS rule where you are applying your font-family?

Answer (score -1):

try using

```
...
unicode-range: U+26;
...
```

HTH

Comment: You are aware that unicode-range is unsupported on Firefox right?

Comment: (because I just tested that that does work on Chrome - different font than you were using because I don't have that available)

Comment: What do you mean? It does provide a functional answer to the question for some browsers. when he said it didn't work for him I requested clarification directly following his comment.